# How to drag around editor panes in Xcode 11?

Tags: xcode, drag-and-drop, editor, wwdc

In one of this year's (2019) WWDC presentations, a speaker briefly demonstrated dragging an editor pane around in a window to reorganise the panes he had open. A thin blue line appears when you're hovering between other editor panes to show you where the pane you're dragging will land. (He did one or two similar actions but didn't reveal how he was doing it.) I can't find anything in the Xcode "help", or online (yet). There are a few posts on reddit regarding Xcode shortcuts but I didn't see any reference to this. Does anyone remember how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the feature I was trying to learn about is called the Destination Chooser. For split pane viewing, to show Xcode 11 where to place the file you want to open, first hold down Option + Shift before clicking on the filename. A blue overlay will appear that can be moved around to the sides of existing open editor panes using the cursor or the arrow keys. When you've reached your destination, just press Enter.

You can see a demo in the [What's New in Xcode 11](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/401/) WWDC video from about 5m5s